Apache Kafka metadata fetch takes more than 40 sec to read and fetch why?
I have three clusters, each with 7 topics and 2 brokers. Each topic is configured with a single partition. Each cluster has one producer and 2 consumers, with the consumers connecting to other clusters. This results in a total of 6 consumers (2 per cluster × 3 clusters) and 3 producers. I have also set up simple ACL authentication using kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer.
The issue I’m facing is with one of the clusters. When I try to fetch metadata using the following code,
List<PartitionInfo> partitions = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);

it takes more than 40 seconds, and I cannot determine the reason. The exact same code and configuration work perfectly on the other clusters with only 300-500ms. All operations, including broker and ZooKeeper setups, are managed using the Java API.
I can’t understand why this delay occurs only on this specific cluster.  Any help in identifying what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.
To assist with troubleshooting, please consider the following before answering: the configuration, code, and overall setup work perfectly on the two clusters running Linux, while the issue occurs only on Windows. This suggests that the problem may not lie in the code or setup but rather in the host environment.
During my investigation, I ensured the following potential causes are not responsible:

Slow Metadata Fetching: I believe this is the root of the problem because during logging it takes too much time to fetch metadata and get the following line(2024-11-23 20:16:54 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106] Cluster ID: bss9f46kS_qHYiScR08meA). The consumer needs metadata about the topic and partitions to determine fetch positions. i observed also that metadata fetching is slow and with Jprofiler I observed delays on updateFetchPositions but I don't know how to solve it
Offset Lookup Delays: I verified that there are no delays, and everything runs smoothly.
Rebalancing Overhead: Logs confirm that no rebalancing processes are occurring.
Large Number of Partitions: This is not an issue in this setup because my topics number are less than 10.
Broker Throttling or Load: I am confident this is not the problem, as there are only two consumers connected.
DNS Issues: This is unlikely since the bootstrap.servers configuration uses IP addresses instead of hostnames.
Windows Defender: i have excluded both JetBrains folder and Kafka, zookeeper path from antivirus which may cause instability but I don't know if there is any firewall behind that causes delays.

Do you have any other suggestions or ideas about what might be causing the issue?
Here is the consumer config:
   Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ip + ":" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_PORT);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupID);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG, groupID);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "13107200");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "536870912");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, "-1");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.SEND_BUFFER_CONFIG, "-1");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "1");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "10");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "60000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "600000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_INCLUDE_JMX_REPORTER_CONFIG, "false");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_METRICS_PUSH_CONFIG, "FALSE");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "300");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, "7000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "300");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, "7000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "11000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "8000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.SOCKET_CONNECTION_SETUP_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "20000");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor");
            props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
            props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
            props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"" + "consumer" + "-" + position + "-" + current_ip + "\" password=\"consumer-secret\";");

Here is the producer config:
   props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_HOST + ":" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_PORT);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, KafkaConfiguration.PRODUCER_GROUP_ID + "-" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_HOST);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "56384");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "1000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "300");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, "7000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "300");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, "7000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "134217728");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "2024000000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, "-1");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.SEND_BUFFER_CONFIG, "-1");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.AUTO_INCLUDE_JMX_REPORTER_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_METRICS_PUSH_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "600000");
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
    props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"producer\" password=\"producer-secret\";");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, RoundRobinPartitioner.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);

Lastly here is the kafka broker config:
kafkaProps.setProperty("broker.id", "0");
kafkaProps.setProperty("log.dirs", zkDir);
kafkaProps.setProperty("zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms", "15000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests", "10");
//kafkaProps.setProperty("zookeeper.set.acl","true");
kafkaProps.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", KafkaConfiguration.ZOOKEEPER_HOST + ":" + KafkaConfiguration.ZOOKEEPER_PORT);
kafkaProps.setProperty("offsets.topic.replication.factor", "1");
kafkaProps.setProperty("delete.topic.enable", "true");
kafkaProps.setProperty("num.network.threads", String.valueOf(this.cores));
kafkaProps.setProperty("num.io.threads", String.valueOf(this.cores * 2));
kafkaProps.setProperty("auto.delete.topics.enable", "true");
kafkaProps.setProperty("auto.create.topics.enable", "false");
kafkaProps.setProperty("auto.leader.rebalance.enable", "false");
kafkaProps.setProperty("background.threads", String.valueOf(this.cores / 2));
kafkaProps.setProperty("metrics.reporters", "");
kafkaProps.setProperty("default.api.timeout.ms", "15000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("log.flush.interval.ms", "15000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("max.connections.per.ip,", "250");
kafkaProps.setProperty("remote.fetch.max.wait.ms,", "10");
kafkaProps.setProperty("message.max.bytes", "2024000000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("socket.request.max.bytes", "2024000000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("fetch.max.bytes", "536870912");
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.consumer.heartbeat.interval.ms", "15000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.consumer.min.heartbeat.interval.ms", "15000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.consumer.max.heartbeat.interval.ms", "45000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.consumer.max.session.timeout.ms", "65000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.consumer.session.timeout.ms", "60000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("replica.fetch.wait.max.ms", "10");
kafkaProps.setProperty("replica.fetch.max.bytes", "13107200");
kafkaProps.setProperty("auto.include.jmx.reporter", "false");
kafkaProps.setProperty("request.timeout.ms", "25");
kafkaProps.setProperty("socket.receive.buffer.bytes", "-1");
kafkaProps.setProperty("compression.type", "lz4");
kafkaProps.setProperty("socket.send.buffer.bytes", "-1");
kafkaProps.setProperty("socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms", "15000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms", "0");
kafkaProps.setProperty("metadata.max.idle.interval.ms", "1500");
kafkaProps.setProperty("metadata.max.retention.ms", "60480000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("session.timeout.ms", "9000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("heartbeat.interval.ms", "14000");
kafkaProps.setProperty("producer.id.expiration.ms", String.valueOf(ConsensusConfiguration.EPOCH_TRANSITION * 2 * ConsensusConfiguration.CONSENSUS_TIMER));
kafkaProps.setProperty("log.retention.ms", String.valueOf(ConsensusConfiguration.EPOCH_TRANSITION * 2 * ConsensusConfiguration.CONSENSUS_TIMER));
kafkaProps.setProperty("authorizer.class.name", "kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer");
kafkaProps.setProperty("listeners", "SASL_PLAINTEXT://" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_HOST + ":" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_PORT);
kafkaProps.setProperty("advertised.listeners", "SASL_PLAINTEXT://" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_HOST + ":" + KafkaConfiguration.KAFKA_PORT);
kafkaProps.setProperty("security.inter.broker.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
kafkaProps.setProperty("sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol", "PLAIN");
kafkaProps.setProperty("sasl.enabled.mechanisms", "PLAIN");
kafkaProps.setProperty("allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found", "false");
kafkaProps.setProperty("listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.sasl.jaas.config", getJaasConfigString());
kafkaProps.setProperty("super.users", getSuperUsers());

Here is an example of kafka-log from the problematic windows machine:
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-13 for epoch 0
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator - [GroupCoordinator 0]: Elected as the group coordinator for partition 28 in epoch 0
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Scheduling loading of offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-28 for epoch 0
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-3 in 4 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 0 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-18 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-41 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-10 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-33 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-48 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-19 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-34 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-4 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-11 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-26 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-49 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-39 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-9 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-24 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-31 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-46 in 5 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-1 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 5 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-16 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-2 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-25 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-40 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-47 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-17 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-32 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-37 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-7 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-22 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-29 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-44 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-14 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-23 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-38 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-8 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-45 in 6 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 6 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-15 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-30 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-0 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-35 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-5 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-20 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-27 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-42 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-12 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-21 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-36 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-6 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-43 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-13 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.c.group.GroupMetadataManager - [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-28 in 7 milliseconds for epoch 0, of which 7 milliseconds was spent in the scheduler.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator - [GroupCoordinator 0]: Static member with groupInstanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116 and unknown member id joins group CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116 in Empty state. Created a new member id CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116-58f4af9b-d6c1-4998-ad87-04561bcdeab0 for this member and add to the group.
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator - [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-7) (reason: Adding new member CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116-58f4af9b-d6c1-4998-ad87-04561bcdeab0 with group instance id Some(CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116); client reason: )
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator - [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116 generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-7) with 1 members
2024-11-23 20:16:46 INFO  k.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator - [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116-58f4af9b-d6c1-4998-ad87-04561bcdeab0 for group CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.106-192.168.1.116 for generation 1. The group has 1 members, 1 of which are static.
2024-11-23 20:16:54 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106] Cluster ID: bss9f46kS_qHYiScR08meA
2024-11-23 20:16:54 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106] Cluster ID: GYgEyPiCTzGEuSJvs9r9xA
2024-11-23 20:17:04 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ClassicKafkaConsumer - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106] Subscribed to topic(s): PREPARE_PHASE, COMMITTEE_PHASE, ANNOUNCE_PHASE, DISPERSE_PHASE2
2024-11-23 20:17:04 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.1.115:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2024-11-23 20:17:04 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ClassicKafkaConsumer - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106] Subscribed to topic(s): PREPARE_PHASE, COMMITTEE_PHASE, ANNOUNCE_PHASE, DISPERSE_PHASE2
2024-11-23 20:17:04 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.1.116:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2024-11-23 20:17:13 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.115-192.168.1.106] (Re-)joining group
Consumer 192.168.1.115 2 started and subscribed to topics: [PREPARE_PHASE, COMMITTEE_PHASE, ANNOUNCE_PHASE, DISPERSE_PHASE2]
2024-11-23 20:17:13 INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, clientId=consumer-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106-CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106, groupId=CONSUMER_PRIVATE_GROUP_ID-192.168.1.116-192.168.1.106] (Re-)joining group
Consumer 192.168.1.116 1 started and subscribed to topics: [PREPARE_PHASE, COMMITTEE_PHASE, ANNOUNCE_PHASE, DISPERSE_PHASE2]
All tasks completed


Can you play around with the METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG to increase it and see if it makes a difference?  Just a guess here.

i've already did. its weird because the exact same settings and code have both clusters and 2 of 3 work decent but the one failed with a delay so I expect that the workaround fix is somewhere else

Does it behave the same without authorizer? If it does you can try sending a Metadata request directly with small tool like https://github.com/adamkotwasinski/kafka-request-tool (it just sends ApiVersions then Metadata to a broker) - if the duration still stays the same, then you've just confirmed it's something on the Kafka broker side.

@Adam Kotwasinski Well, I spent countless hours trying to identify the source of the issue, and I started thinking it might not be a Kafka problem, but I'm not entirely sure. For example, ZooKeeper takes 15-20 seconds to bootstrap, whereas in my VMware environment with fewer CPU/RAM resources, it only takes 150ms plus 400-700ms for kafka fetching metadata. As I mentioned before, the code and configurations are exactly the same. My first thought was that maybe Windows Defender is slowing down IntelliJ, so I excluded it from real-time protection, but the problem persists.

@Adam Kotwasinski I also tried increasing the ZooKeeper buffer with the command System.setProperty("zookeeper.jute.maxbuffer", "4194304");. I’ve even changed ZooKeeper's port and host, but the delay remains the same. What else can I do? Can you suggest any solutions?

@MixalisNavridis ZooKeeper takes 15-20 seconds to bootstrap - yeah it feels like host-specific magic, no clue there (and it's Windows too!). In the past I also experienced some slow-downs related to running in Docker (dunno if that's your case), FWIW for my development tools I run everything locally. HTH

locally == no Docker, straight on kafka-server-start.sh on the dev machine (I have some util at https://github.com/adamkotwasinski/kafkaenv/blob/main/setup-kafka.sh if lazy)

@Adam Kotwasinski
The delays with ZooKeeper were fixed. The culprit wasn't in the code or the IntelliJ IDE but on my local machine. Specifically, my machine was connected to a network adapter that was for VirtualBox and used IPv6. The resolution of the gateway was different. I just disabled it and connected my machine to the correct network adapter. Voilà, my ZooKeeper issue is fixed! But the delay problem with fech partition still persists any guess?

Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper. Remove that

Finally, I found the answer to my problem. It was very tough to figure out what was really happening. I struggled a lot, and it consumed me hundreds of hours of searching and debugging. The issue was not with the Kafka configuration or API, but a network issue. Specifically, the resolution of the hostname for the IP address of the Ubuntu VM was local, so Windows couldn't resolve the correct hostname from the /etc/hosts file. Kafka handles the exception, but the method runs until a timeout occurs, causing the delay in fetching topic metadata.
Here are the detailed steps to quickly fix the problem:
Make sure ipv4 is enabled or use it programmatically
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Steps to Change Hostname:
Open Terminal: Press Ctrl + Alt + T to open the terminal. Check Current Hostname: To see the current hostname, type:
 hostnamectl

This will display the current hostname along with other system information. Set New Hostname: To change the hostname, use the following command:
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname myvmhostname

Replace new-hostname with the desired hostname.
Verify Change: To confirm the change, run:
sh hostnamectl

You should see the new hostname listed under the "Static hostname" section.
Go to windows and do the following: Open the Hosts File: In Notepad, click on File > Open.
Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.
Select the hosts file. If you don't see it, make sure to change the file type filter to "All Files" at the bottom right1.
Add the IP Address and Hostname:
At the end of the file, add a new line with the IP address of your virtual machine followed by the hostname you want to map. For example:
192.168.1.100    myvmhostname

Save the changes by pressing Ctrl + S or clicking on File > Save
then run the following command in the terminal:
ipconfig /flushdns


Glad you figured it out, but 1) Kafka isn't designed to run in windows 2) you shouldn't be touching hosts files at all other than remove 127.0.1.1 from Ubuntu defaults 3) Kafka runs fine with ipv6 in my experience, so preferring ipv4 did what exactly?
